# How can we get parent package annotations?Anyone offer an example?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, package

Imagine that we have a class:`User.java` below package: `src/service/model`

And we can get the *package* (`src/service/model`) *annotations*
using `User.class.getPackage().getAnnotaions();`

Then How can we get the *parent package* (`src/service`) *annotations*.

I don't know how to get *package annotations* in a skip level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all packages in app and than filter required package to get `Annotations`:

```
String userPackName = User.class.getPackage().getName();      // src.service.model
int lastIndex = userPackName.lastIndexOf(".");
String parentPackName = userPackName.substring(0, lastIndex); // src.service
Annotation[] annotations = Arrays.stream(Package.getPackages())
                .filter(pack -> pack.getName().equals(parentPackName))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Package::getAnnotations)
                .orElseGet(() -> new Annotation[0]);
```

, but `Package.getPackages()` will only return the packages defined in the `current class loader` (any classes from root package (src/service) were loaded by `current class loader`).

`java.lang.Package` snippet:

```
@CallerSensitive
public static Package[] getPackages() {
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getClassLoader(Reflection.getCallerClass());
    return cl != null ? cl.getPackages() : (Package[])BootLoader.packages().toArray((x$0) -> {
        return new Package[x$0];
    });
}

/** @deprecated */
@CallerSensitive
@Deprecated(
    since = "9"
)
public static Package getPackage(String name) {
    ClassLoader l = ClassLoader.getClassLoader(Reflection.getCallerClass());
    return l != null ? l.getPackage(name) : BootLoader.getDefinedPackage(name);
}
```

Comment: ```$xslt
 Optional<Annotation[]> obj1 = Arrays.stream(Package.getPackages())
                .filter(pack -> pack.getName().equals("com.goods.center.backend.controller"))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Package::getAnnotations);

 Optional<Annotation[]> obj2 = Arrays.stream(Package.getPackages())
         .filter(pack -> pack.getName().equals("com.goods.center.backend.controller.merchant"))
         .findFirst()
         .map(Package::getAnnotations);
```
annother problem encountered. obj1 is empty.obj2 is not empty. Why obj1 is empty?

Comment: The `java.lang.Package.getPackages()` method gets all the packages currently known for the caller's ClassLoader instance. Those packages correspond to classes loaded via or accessible by name to that ClassLoader instance. If the caller's ClassLoader instance is the bootstrap ClassLoader instance, which may be represented by null in some implementations, only packages corresponding to classes loaded by the bootstrap ClassLoader instance will be returned.

Comment: The caller is the code in this answer. So it is surely not loaded by the bootstrap loader. But why using this stream to search all packages? Why not just use `Annotation[] annotations = Package.getPackage(parentPackName).getAnnotations();`?

Comment: `@Deprecated(since="9")
public static Package getPackage​(String name)`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getPackage-java.lang.String-

Comment: @kozmo@Holger Thank you for your instructions. The last one : If no class under "com.service",despite many class under "com.service.model",the API Package.getPackage("com.service") will return null.I don't know why.

Comment: @Kesa_Wu - `Package.getPackage(...)` will only return a non-null value if the current ClassLoader is already aware of the package. `.getPackage(...)` & `.getPackage() `use the same approach to get ClassLoader: `ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getClassLoader(Reflection.getCallerClass())`. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993418/package-getpackage-in-java-returning-null

Comment: @kozmo Sorry,in the upper case,the API Package.getPackage("com.service") returned Optional.Empty.I guess it is caused by the package "com.service" that no classes loaded from it.

Comment: @Kesa_Wu - y.  -> `Package.getPackage("com.service")` return `null`

Comment: @kozmo Thank you.I just got messed up. and I am clear now.